# Spring-boot location variables in urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up my website to allow location additions to the urls.
EG: mysite.com/us/ca/sanfrancisco/home
While also still allowing mysite.com/home and everything in between.

Spring boot parent so you know what version of spring I'm using:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

If there's another piece of versioning you need, let me know.

I get that I can add in regex variables to the request mapping, but how would I go about persisting those urls across more requests?

So right now for an example, the testing error page I have:

```
    @RequestMapping({"/error/501", "/{state:[a-z]{2}}/error/501", "/{state:[a-z]{2}}/{city:[a-z]+}/error/501"})
    public ModelAndView testingLocations(ModelMap model, @PathVariable(value="state", required = false) String state,
                                         @PathVariable(value="city", required=false) String city){
        getLogger().info("State: {}", state);
        model.addAttribute("stateTest",state+":"+city);
        model.addAttribute("view", "error");
        return new ModelAndView("error/501", model);
    }
```

But when I'm on my testing page, and I click the home button, it takes me back to mysite.com/home

**So My Questions**

Is there a way for me to persist it so that if they're currently on a location based url, it will apply that base to the future navigations? (unless they manually enter the url to not include them)

Then as a follow-up, is there a way for me to globally apply these request variables without requiring me to add the @PathVariable to every request mapping method? I get that I can just add the request mapping variable strings themselves to the controller class, so that I don't need those on every method. But is there a way for me to utilize those without needing the @PathVariable annotations?

Finally, is there a way for me to make this not as hardcoded, like a way for me to say /{*location}/error to cover as deep as the locations will allow? While still having the verification on the location formatting, so verifying that 1 we support the locations given, 2 the format is correct (/ca/sanfrancisco vs /anything/anything

The last one I can live with, if I need to have the /state/city/municipality/actualtarget 
As far as verifying that we support the locations given, I understand that's on my end, which I'll probably just have a small database to keep track of where we do and do not support for the given variables.

Is there a best practice for building this system? I tried to find something on this, but googling "spring boot location url" is not the best at giving me what I need, since "location" can apply to a pretty wide range of topics. I've gotten to where I am from searching, but I can't seem to pin down these last few steps.

Any help/advice/suggestions is appreciated. If upgrading versions is required, I'm not sure how viable that is at the moment, I'd have to look into it. Preferably I'd like the solution to be able to be done on the current spring version I'm running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way here is:

```java
@RequestMapping("/some/{foo}/{baz}")
public String hi(CompositeObject compositeObject) {
   return "hi";
}

@Data
public class CompositeObject {
    private String foo;
    private String baz;
}
```

Spring provides functionality for request path and request parameters to collect it into a composite object. It doesn' work either with body or headers.

If you have something optional like *state*, then just keep it null at the controller and handle later

Comment: Any suggestions on how to persist the URL across future requests? Or am I going to have to just append them to all of the outgoing urls on the page as they're loaded?

It sounds like you're suggesting I go with the "/{state:[a-z]{2}}/{city:[a-z]+}/error/501" mapping at controller level tactic.

Comment: I guess you will have to declare at every controller `/error` endpoint because it must be declared somehow. You can reuse code close inside these endpoints by creating some `ErrorService` which takes some `CompositeObject` as input parameter

Comment: My apologies, I copy pasted more than I meant to.
@RequestMapping("/{state:[a-z]{2}}/{city:[a-z]+}/")
would be the base request mapping I'd have to put above every controller, then add in the @ParamValue's for state/city in every method, which could forward down to our "global" settings, and I have to append these onto the urls inside of the other classes, so my home button would be (in html)
th:href="@{'/'+state+'/'+city+'/home'}"
(as an example, obviously there'd be the null checks and such)

Was how I was thinking about it, but that just seems really messy.

Comment: You have to declare every path (i.e `/state`) explicitly and use one class for all the `PathVariable`. That's the only way) There will be a lot of request mappings, one error service and one DTO class for paths

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I'll take a look at implementing this.